# How to dynamically set and modify CSS in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some JavaScript code that creates some `div` elements and it sets their CSS properties.
Because I would like to decouple CSS logic from my JavaScript code and because CSS is easier to read in its own `.css` file, I would like to set the CSS `className` of my element and then dynamically inject some values into the defined CSS property.

Here is what I would like to do :

`style.css`:

```
.myClass { 
    width: $insertedFromJS 
}
```

`script.js`:

```
var myElement = document.createElement("div");
myElement.className = "myClass";
```

I want to do something like this but at that point `myElement.style.width` is empty

```
myElement.style.width.replaceAll("$insertedFromJS", "400px");
```

I think my problem here is that after the call to `myElement.className = "myClass"`, the CSS is not yet applied.

Comment: When are you running the JS?  Immediately?  `onload`?  `ondocumentready`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question.  Are you trying to affect all elements with the class `myClass` or just the one you have just created?

Comment: I'm with James on this one.  After giving an answer to the question and then re-reading it, I'm actually confused as to what the purpose of something like this would even be.  You want to "decouple" your JS and CSS by creating a CSS stylesheet that depends on Javascript to inject / replace the proper values that you are going to hard code into your Javascript code?  That's pretty much the exact opposite of what the word "decouple" means.

Comment: Well ok not decouple on the object oriented way...wrong naming on my part. The goal for me is just to change the code so it is more readable. I am trying to change multiple element, since each element has a different value. I think the best is just to create a js method which purpose is only to set CSS props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, it sounds like you're trying to set placeholder text in your css file, and then use javascript to parse out the text with the css value you want to set for that class. You can't do that in the way you're trying to do it. In order to do that, you'd have to grab the content of the CSS file out of the dom, manipulate the text, and *then* save it back to the DOM. But that's a really overly-complicated way to go about doing something that...

```
myElement.style.width = "400px";
```

...can do for you in a couple of seconds. I know it doesn't really address the issue of decoupling css from js, but there's not really a *whole* lot you can do about that. You're trying to set css dynamically, after all.

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you might want to try defining multiple classes and just changing the className property in your js.

Comment: I just wanted to use my css file as a template and inject my variables in it but i guess its not the best approach for that kind of technology, i will stay with my javascript CSS implementation. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Setting the style, might be accomplished defining the inner-page style declaration.

Here is what i mean

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.cssText = '.cssClass { color: #F00; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
document.getElementById('someElementId').className = 'cssClass';
```

However the  part of modifying it can be a lot of tricky than you think. Some regex solutions might do a good job. But here is another way, I found.

```
if (!document.styleSheets) return;
var csses = new Array();
if (document.styleSheets[0].cssRules)  // Standards Compliant {
   csses = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
}
else {         
   csses = document.styleSheets[0].rules;  // IE 
}
for (i=0;i<csses.length;i++) {
   if ((csses[i].selectorText.toLowerCase()=='.cssClass') || (thecss[i].selectorText.toLowerCase()=='.borders'))
   {
     thecss[i].style.cssText="color:#000";
   }
}
```

Comment: 1. Do not use `.innerHTML`. Use `<HTMLStyleElement>.textContent` or `<HTMLHeadElement>.appendChild(document.createTextNode('...'))` instead. 2. This does no work in old IE versions. For IE, access `<HTMLStyleElement>.styleSheet.cssText='...'.

Answer (score 0):

could you use jQuery on this? You could use

```
$(".class").css("property", val); /* or use the .width property */
```

Comment: The tag for this post is about javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: @Oscar Jara - As far as I remember jQuery is 100% javascript. But never the less that is why he asked if jQuery would be a possibility I guess

Comment: jQuery is Javascript, but Javascript is not jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

There is a jQuery plugin called jQuery Rule,
http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html

I tried it to dynamically set some div sizes of a board game. It works in FireFox, not in Chrome. I didn't try IE9.